# Send email with multiple lines of info instead of individual emails

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am following this blog post: https://mailtrap.io/blog/send-emails-from-google-sheet/
I need to send one email to each 'rep' with a table of each row of the sheet to which their name is attached. Right now, it is sending individual emails for each row with their email.

**Google Sheets data:**

number  types    owner   rep     assistant  email   subject

1   square  Alice   ovc jlc test1@gmail.com Update

2   round   Robert  ovc jlc test1@gmail.com Update

3   round   Robert  khr jlc test2@gmail.com Update

4   square  Alice   khr jlc test2@gmail.com Update

5   square  Robert  khr jlc test2@gmail.com Update

**Code:**

```
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:G");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];
    const number = row[0];
    const type = row[1];
    const owner = row[2];
    const rep = row[3];
    const assistant = row[4];
    const email = row[5];
    const subject = row[6];

    console.log(`Row ${i + 2}: ${number}, ${type}, ${owner}, ${rep}, ${assistant}, ${email}, ${subject}`); // Logging the data

    if (!email) {
      console.log(`Row ${i + 2}: Email address is missing. Skipping this row.`);
      continue;
    }

    const message = createEmailMessage(number, type, owner, rep, assistant);
function createEmailMessage(number, type, owner, rep, assistant) {
  const message = `Dear ${rep},

Please update if you are no longer the Rep of the following types:
  Number    Type        Owner        Rep         Assistant
  ${number} ${type} ${owner}    ${rep}      ${assistant} 

Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.`;

  return message;
}

    try {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
      console.log(`Row ${i + 2}: Email sent to ${email}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Row ${i + 2}: Error sending email to ${email}. Error message: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

**Email wanted:**

Dear rep,

Please update if you are no longer the Rep of the following types:

number  types    owner   rep     assistant  email   subject

1   square  Alice   ovc jlc test1@gmail.com Update

4   square  Alice   khr jlc test2@gmail.com Update

**Problem:**

The emails actually sent are individual for each row so 'Alice' would get two emails. It would be great if there was an actual table in the email.

Comment: Don't use [tag:gsheets] in Google Sheets questions; use [tag:google-sheets]. There is a Python project called `gsheets`, which is a wrapper for the Google Sheets API; while it's related, it's not help to include it on questions that aren't related to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. It's not easy to setup a testbed so I just didn't do it.

I wasn't sure about what to do for the subject so I just put them in an array and joined them with commas.

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange("A2:G" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var mObj = { mA: [] }
  vs.forEach(([number, type, owner, rep, assistant, email, subject], i) => {
    if (!mObj.hasOwnProperty(email)) {
      mObj[email] = [{ n: number, t: type, o: owner, r: rep, a: assistant, s: subject }];
      mObj.mA.push(email);
    } else {
      mObj[email].push({ n: number, t: type, o: owner, r: rep, a: assistant, s: subject });
    }
  })
  mObj.mA.forEach(em => {
    let msg = `Dear ${mObj[rep][0]},<br>Please update if you are no longer the Rep of the following types:<br>`;
    let sub = [];
    msg += `<style>th,td{border:1px,solid,black}</style><table><tr><th>Number</th><th>Types</th><th>Owner</th><th>Rep</th><th>Assistant</th><th>Email</th><th>Subject</th></tr>`
    mObj[em].forEach(obj => {
      msg += `<tr><td>${obj.n}</td><td>${obj.t}</td><td>${obj.o}</td><td>${obj.r}</td><td>${obj.a}</td><td>${em}</td><td>${obj.s}</td></tr>`;
      sub.push(obj.s);
    });
    msg += `</table><br>Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.`;
    MailApp.sendEmail(em, sub.join(','), null, { htmlBody: msg });
  });
}
```